# mongrel_rails cluster::start does not work, looks for daemons/daemonize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel, mongrel-cluster

I'm having a mongrel_cluster.yml file with the below content:

```
cat mongrel_cluster.yml
---
port: "8000"
servers: 2
pid_file: tmp/pids/mongrel.pid
log_file: log/mongrel.log
cwd: /home/directory
```

When i try to start

```
mongrel_rails cluster::start
```

it says that

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- daemons/daemonize
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1033
```

I do not have root access. However i have seen [this](http://myridia.com/dev_posts/view/62) link i assume that we need not have any root access just to test the command as said in point numbe 5 in the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/54226 This was the ruby-forum post by Zed Shaw about a Mongrel release. The problem is with `mongrel_rails` script (not a gem)

`mongrel_rails` uses daemons gem and that's why the error. Install it by:

```
gem install daemons
```